# How to pass data from a struct through a tableview controller to a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

In my app I'm trying to pass data from a struct with variables to my main view controller through my table view. I made a data model to pass my variables to the main view controller..

My Struct looks like this:

```
    Struct VocabBuilder {
var n1LevelVocab: [Vocab] = [Vocab(vocabTitle: "上達", vocabHiragana: "じょうたつ", englishTranslation: "Improvement", noOfTimesSeen: 0),
                          Vocab(vocabTitle: "乗り越える", vocabHiragana: "のりこえる", englishTranslation: "To Push Through", noOfTimesSeen: 0),
                          Vocab(vocabTitle: "耐久性", vocabHiragana: "たいきゅうせい", englishTranslation: "Durability", noOfTimesSeen: 0)]
}
```

I pass my data to my main view controller with this func in the same struct

```
 mutating func returnAllWordDataForN1() -> (vocab:String, hiragana:String, englishTranslation:String, viewCount: Int) {
        
        n1LevelVocab[vocabNumber].incrementNoOfTimesSeen()
        //has to be mutating because structs are immutable and this is a var in the vocabInfo.swift file.
        
        return (n1LevelVocab[vocabNumber].vocabTitle, n1LevelVocab[vocabNumber].vocabHiragana, n1LevelVocab[vocabNumber].englishTranslation, n1LevelVocab[vocabNumber].noOfTimesSeen)
    }
```

I have a function in my main view controller to load these values into UITextLabels:

```
func loadUI() {

        vocabBox?.text = vocabInfo.returnAllWordDataForN1().0            
        hiraganaBox?.text = vocabInfo.returnAllWordDataForN1().1
        hiraganaBox?.textColor = view.backgroundColor         
        englishTranslationBox?.text = vocabInfo.returnAllWordDataForN1().2           
        viewCount?.text = ("View Count: \(vocabInfo.returnAllWordDataForN1().3)")     
            correctOrIncorrectBox?.text = "Try and Remember!"
            correctOrIncorrectBox?.textColor = .white   
        }
```

I call this function in viewDidLoad and it shows all the data from the struct no problem. However I want to assign each of these functions to load when the tableview cell is selected.

```
let nLevelArray = ["N1","N2","N3","N4","N5"]
```

In my tableView I've set up the usual functions like number of rows in section, and cell for row at however when I try to use performSegue I can't get it to call the function in view did load.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

 //destination.vocabBox?.text = testArray[indexPath!.row)]
            //destination.loadUI() = nLevelArray[indexPath?.row]
    }
```

**Things I've tried:**
I tried using didSelectRow from indexPath but it is loading the storyboard file I have twice when I use the navigationController pushToViewController function. It still doesn't call the load ui functions.

I also tried to use a variable var dataArray = Vocab to make my struct into a variable to pass it in the tableView and also tried loading up the data from the struct in an array

```
   var levelSelected = [VocabBuilder().n1LevelVocab, VocabBuilder().n2LevelVocab,VocabBuilder().n3LevelVocab, VocabBuilder().n4LevelVocab, VocabBuilder().n5LevelVocab]
```

When I test my app on the simulator it just shows the main storyboard in its default state with none of the data loaded. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I want to help you solve this problem but I still can't really get the sense of your problem. I didn't understand the core problem because of the source code with so many custom types. Can you simplify your question with specific focuses, hierarchy or outline the core problem ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes sorry this is my first app and even I’m having difficulty explaining the root cause of the problem...so basically I have one function which loads the data from the struct into ui labels in the view controller. In my app I have a table view that I want to load the function when a cell is selected depending on the cell in the table view that was selected N1, N2. I can give more info in a DM.

Comment: in what/which DM?

Comment: Sorry I’ll just add a link to my project on GitHub so you can see how it’s all connected. https://github.com/AE542/ProtoKanjiV.3